# error code 38 - "id parameter is missing." in twitter

Tags: ios, twitter

I am using following code in my iOS app, to favourite a tweet by particular tweet id.

```
+ (void)favTweetForUser:(NSString )tweet_id withAccount:(ACAccount)twitterAccounts andCompletion:(resultCompletion)completion
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/favorites/create.json"];
    NSNumber * myNumber =[NSNumber numberWithLongLong:[tweet_id longLongValue]];
    NSDictionary *params = @{@"id" : myNumber};

    [self postRequestWithAcc:twitterAccounts param:params url:url andCompletion:completion];
}
```

I am getting following response from twitter

```
{
errors = (
{
code = 38;
message = "id parameter is missing.";
}
);
}
```

I am not understanding this error, I am passing "id" parameter, but still getting that error, please suggest me changes to work it

Comment: Show your `postRequestWithAcc:aran:url:andCompletion:` method. Log the URL. Verify the `id` is really passed.

Comment: Yes, I am sure the "id" is really passed, even I passed the constant long integer but still getting the same error, and the method "postRequestWithAcc" is common for my all API calls, this method is working for retweet but not working for favourite.